# PaintDotNet (paint.net) can't be installed because of a missing .msi file

Tags: windows-7, installation, paint.net

[image]

No matter what I do, I can't seem to install paint.net because that .msi is missing, but I only have paint.net.4.0.21.install.exe, and unzipping it with gzip there's only

- NDP471-KB4033344-Web.exe
- PaintDotNet_x64.msi
- PaintDotNet_x86.msi

Renaming PaintDotNet_x64.msi to PaintDotNet_x64_738154315.msi doesn't do anything.

Anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: I suspect you might need to re-download the installer. It looks like it's trying to find a specific MSI, in which case renaming the existing ones won't help if they're the wrong build. Installer EXEs often wrap the MSI, so I'd expect this to work straight off.

Comment: You should contact your IT Administrator for assistance.  In order to solve this, you will have to supply the exact same installer they originally used.  If this is a personal computer, it was likely removed, when you cleaned temporary files.  Installation files like are typically kept until you remove the software unless you take (extraordinary steps) to remove them.

Comment: [You will have to determine the product code for the current version of Paint.NET and replace the previous product code in the registry.](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/32279-cant-find-msi-to-repair-or-reinstal-or-update-my-paint/).  Due to a lack of details about what version you are using currently, what causes the message to appear, I am unable to submit an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a registry editor, in my case, OO Registry Editor, search for paint string, and carefully delete everything related to paint.net.

Careful though, because paint.net and paint are 2 different things. The later is an integral part of Windows OS. Not sure about Win 10 though, I use Win 7.